# Libraries included in Compile Sources are not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have included SBJson libraries in my project, with copy option checked, and they are listed in the Build Phase/Compile Sources section. Despite when I type #import "SBJson.h" " autocomplete suggests SBJson.h, when I compile the project it fails with "file not found" error. I have checked Search paths values and all seems to be fine, but the issue still persists.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you link the binary with libraries?
Did you include the header search paths?

Comment: How about target dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding all the source files into your project and then call:

```
#import "SBJson.h"
```